# Adapter is not updated on using search view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This is basically a notes app,in which we dynamically add data to our app by taking in title and description from the user,the problem is that when we search about some note by its title then instead of giving the possible notes the data set in the adapter vanishes,the logic is written in my filter() function in the adapter class

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
private ArrayList<Notes> list;
private NotesAdapter notesAdapter;//this is our notes adapter
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
@Override //
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    list=new ArrayList<>();//this is the list which we have to pass into adapter
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.rv);
    notesAdapter=new NotesAdapter(this,list);
    View dialogView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_main,null,false);
    final EditText title=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.t);
    final EditText description=dialogView.findViewById(R.id.d);
    final AlertDialog alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Enter the details:")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    list.add(new Notes(title.getText().toString(),description.getText().toString(),false));
                    notesAdapter.notifyItemChanged(list.size());
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }).create();


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override // on pressing the fab we will get an alert dialog box where we can add title and description and with the option to add it or not 
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
    linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}``

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.search) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
    notesAdapter.filter(s);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
    notesAdapter.filter(s);
    return true;
}
```

**NotesAdapter.java**

```
 public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Notes> arrayList;
    private ArrayList<Notes> arrayListCopy;
    Context c;
    NotesAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notes> list){
        this.arrayList=list;
        this.c=context;
         this.arrayListCopy=new ArrayList<>(list);//this is where I store identical list which I get from Adapter
    }
    public class NotesHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;
        public NotesHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public NotesAdapter.NotesHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new NotesHolder(LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.item_row,parent,false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final NotesAdapter.NotesHolder holder, final int position) {
              final Notes currentNote=arrayList.get(position);
        holder.textView.setText(currentNote.getTitle());
        holder.textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
               arrayList.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
               notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
               return true;
           }
       });
        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(c,AnotherActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("NAME",currentNote.getDescription());
                c.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

     public void filter(String text){//This is my filter function 
        arrayList.clear();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(text)){
            arrayList.addAll(arrayListCopy);
        }
        else{
            text=text.toLowerCase();
            for(Notes note:arrayListCopy){
                if(note.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                    arrayList.add(note);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();//the data set is still not updated and instead it vanishes
    }
}
```

As soon as I search something the whole list gets vanished ,where am I missing out on?How should I modify my filter function in adapter class?

Comment: First check whether your filter is working correctly, by searching a string and printing `arraylist`

Comment: `arrayList` and `arrayListCopy` are references to the same list. Changes done to one of them, will be reflected in both. For example `arrayList.clear()` will also empty the `arrayListCopy` list.

Comment: i have made that change but still the data set somehow vanishes as soon as I type something in search box

Answer (score 0):

Change your getItemCount :

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListCopy.size();
}
```

Comment: No. In this code `arrayList` represents the data for the `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `arrayList` and `arrayListCopy` are references to the same list.

```
NotesAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notes> list){
    this.arrayList=list;
    this.c=context;
    this.arrayListCopy=list;
}
```

Changes done to one of them, will be reflected in both. For example `arrayList.clear()` will also empty the `arrayListCopy` list.

What you could do is something like this:

```
List<Notes> originalList;
NotesAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notes> list){
    this.arrayList=list;
    this.c=context;
    this.originalList= new ArrayList<>(list); // create a new List that contains all the elements of `list`.
}
```

And to filter, do this:

```
public void filter(String text){ 
    arrayList.clear();
    if(text.isEmpty()){
        arrayList.addAll(originalList);
    } else{
        text=text.toLowerCase();
        for(Notes note : originalList){
            if(note.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                arrayList.add(note);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

It seems that you're adding items to the `list` inside the `MainActivity` after you create the adapter which means that you'll have to use some other mechanism for adding new items so that `originalList` will contain all the items. Something like:

```
public class NotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotesAdapter.NotesHolder> {
     public void addItem(Notes item){
         originalList.add(item);
         if(text.isEmpty() || item.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
             arrayList.add(item);
         }
     }
}
```

Here, `text` is just a reference to the `text` variable passed to the `filter` method.
From `MainActivity` when a new item is created, do this:

```
adapter.addItem(new Notes(title.getText().toString(),description.getText().toString(),false));
```

Comment: I have made the exact changes but still as soon as I type something in searchview box ,the data set vanishes i.e the adapter is not updating

Comment: @TanishqSaluja That is unusual. Are you sure you're creating the `originalList` using `new ArrayList<>(list);` ?

Comment: @TanishqSaluja Actually, after taking a better look at your question, it seems that you're adding items to the `list` inside your activity after you create the adapter. That means that you will have to update the `originalList` list as well.

Comment: @TanishqSaluja I've edited my answer to address that.

Comment: Great! This works,but I still dont get the point that why our originalList will not get updated when we add items to arrayList even if it was created before we created the adapter ?why werent the changes reflected when we just doing list.add() and not adapter.additem() ?

Comment: @TanishqSaluja That is because in this version, there is no link between `originalList` and `list` because of the way `originalList` was defined (`this.originalList= new ArrayList<>(list);`). `new ArrayList<>(list)` creates a completely new list that has all the elements of `list` but is not linked to that `List`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Titus :D, if possible then answer my this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244682/invoke-interface-method-in-adapter-class-for-callback-method-using-fragments

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NotesAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notes> list){
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
    this.c=context;
     this.arrayListCopy=new ArrayList<>(list);//this is where I store identical list which I get from Adapter
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

 public void filter(String text){//This is my filter function 
    arrayList.clear();
    if(text.trim().isEmpty() || text == null){
        arrayList.addAll(arrayListCopy);
    }
    else{
        text=text.toLowerCase();
        for(Notes note:arrayListCopy){
            if(note.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(text)){
                arrayList.add(note);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();//the data set is still not updated and instead it vanishes
}
```

Original Answer:

Here you are referencing the same variable (i.e. `arrayList` and `arrayListCopy` ) are pointing to the same variable. Instead, initialize `arrayList` like this inside your constructor:

```
this.arrayList = new ArrayList<>(arrayListCopy.size());
```

Comment: This will create a new **empty** `ArrayList` with an initial capacity equal to `arrayListCopy.size()`. [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)) you can find more details about this constructor.

Comment: Yes. And that's ok. Because the individual records are added later in the filter